# pywinauto: set_focus() в многопоточном приложении

Tags: pywinauto

Мое приложение (скрипт) это робот который автоматизирует некие действия пользователя в **SAPGUI**.
Ввиду того что некоторые операции со стороны **SAP** затягиваются на минуты, мне приходится создавать несколько сессий внутри **SAPGUI**, для экономии времени. Каждая сессия в **SAPGUI** это  одно окно(с одним хэндлом) внутри которого сменяются формы. В процессе работы вызываются диалоговые окна принадлежащие этому окну.
Синхронизация работы потоков осуществляется через `threading.RLock()`. Такой в принципе простой классический мультипоток.
Естественно каждый раз входя в блок `acquire()/release()` приходится переключать фокус на необходимое окно сессии, с чем в принципе справляется метод `set_focus()`, пока не заходит речь о диалоговых окнах.

Используется следующая функция ожидания диалога для мультипотока :

```
def wait_dialog(self, name, timeout=SAP_OPERATION_TIMEOUT):
    ActionLogger.log(f'Wait for "{name}"')

    def check_state(window):
        with lock:
            new_window = window.window(title_re=name, class_name=class_names.dialog)
            new_window.verify_actionable()
        return(new_window)

    new_window = pywinauto.timings.wait_until_passes(timeout, 0.1, lambda: check_state(self.window))
    return(SapWindow(new_window))
```

где `lock` это экземпляр класса `RLock`.

Так вот в следующем куске кода `set_focus()` делает диалог активным, и якобы сфокусированным (`is_active() == True`), но нет фокуса ни на одном элементе и `type_keys()` ничего выполнить не может и ошибок не выдает. В то время как `Button2.click()` отлично срабатывает:

```
dlg4 = sess.wait_dialog(sess.name, timeout=SAPbot.SAP_SPOOL_TIMEOUT)

with SAPbot.lock:
    dlg4.set_focus()
    dlg4.window.type_keys(filename + '{TAB 6}' + workDir)
    dlg4.window.Button2.click()
```

Если же заменить `dlg4.set_focus()` на `SetForegroundWindow(dlg4.window.wrapper_object().handle)`, то все будет отлично работать под **Windows 10**, но не на **Windows Server 2012** через **RDP**. Под серверной виндой при выполнении третьим потоком (почему именно при третьем выполнении - я не знаю) этого куска кода, значек **SAPGUI** начинает мигать и дальше та же история что и с `set_focus()`, только окно даже не появляется. Я понимаю что мигание означает что винда не может переключить фокус ибо я якобы работаю с другим окном, на самом деле нет - доступ к окнам атомарный через `RLock`, как я уже писал выше.

Но есть одно интересное решение [LockSetForegroundWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-locksetforegroundwindow): если использовать для фокусировки следующий код все работает корректно:

```
if not dlg4.window.is_active():
    dlg4.window.type_keys('{VK_MENU}')
    SetForegroundWindow(dlg4.window.wrapper_object().handle)
```

Comment: Вообще, `SetForegroundWindow` вызывается внутри `.set_focus()` (это, наверно, и так понятно). Но фишка Python'а в том, что у него потоки выполняются не параллельно, а в режиме разделения времени. Соответственно, переключения контекста происходят в произвольные моменты. Если действие под фокусом - не одно, то переключение может произойти посередине и фокус уйдёт на другое окно в другом потоке. `LockSetForegroundWindow` действительно может решить часть проблемы, но не в 100% случаев.

Comment: Идеальный вариант - обойтись вообще без `type_keys()` и `click_input()`, чтобы фокус не требовался. Например, для `backend="win32"` есть метод `.send_keystrokes()` который использует `WM_KEYDOWN` и `WM_KEYUP`, а также `WM_ACTIVATE`. Он поддерживает и комбинации клавиш (хотя их работа не гарантируется для всех приложений), и даже активную раскладку использует (можно попробовать `^N` на русской раскладке, кстати, вдруг сработает, хотя вряд ли).

Comment: Ну, или в потоке под локом должно быть всё, что является атомарным (между фокусом и концом атомарной последовательности), а не только ожидание `.verify_actionable()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вспомнил про этот вопрос - решил закрыть.
В процессе эксплуатации вышеуказанный метод показал себя ненадежным. Поиски в интернете привели к следующему решению:

```
window.set_focus()
if not window.is_active():
    current_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    mine_TID = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
    current_TID = win32functions.GetWindowThreadProcessId(current_handle, None)
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(mine_TID, current_TID, 1)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(window.handle)
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(mine_TID, current_TID, 0)
```

Но периодически это не срабатывало из-за многим знакомой ошибки:

```
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')
```

Дальнейший поиск и комбинирование существующих решений привели к такому странноватому, но рабочему варианту:

```
window.set_focus()
if not window.is_active():
    current_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    mine_TID = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
    current_TID = win32functions.GetWindowThreadProcessId(current_handle, None)
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(mine_TID, current_TID, 1)
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(window.handle, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)  
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(window.handle, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)  
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(window.handle, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW + win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(mine_TID, current_TID, 0)
```

Актуально и для pywinauto-0.6.8
**P.S.**:

- Нет возможности избавиться от `type_keys()`.
- Когда все под локом работает отлично, но для моей задачи такое решение не оптимально по времени, а это критично.